# How to check if Parameter in Function like Macro is defined

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I like to check if the argument of `PARA(s)` has been defined or, in case this is not possible, if it is an integer.

```
#define PARA_STR(s) "<PARA"#s">"
#define PARA(s) PARA_STR(s)
#define ID 10

char str1[] = "Test" PARA(ID); // =Test<PARA10>
char str2[] = "Test2" PARA(ID2); // =Test2<PARAID2>
```

The definition of `str2` should result in an error.

I need to point out that the definition might be used in global definitions

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: are there any limitation where `PARA` macro can appear?

Comment: it is always used for string initializing. Local and global.

Comment: I'm afraid, this is not possible with macros.

Comment: what does "defined" mean? that macro `ID` is defined? or that the identifier is defined like `enum { ID = 10; }` ?

Comment: @tstanisl Currently we use `#define ID 10` but `enum { ID = 10, }` would be possible .

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to find a reliable solution.
If `PARA` was used for initialization of `char*` then it `PARA` could expand to `PARA_STR(s)` followed by `+` and a constant expression of value 0 that is dependent on `s`.
For example:

```
#define PARA_STR(s) "<PARA"#s">"
#define PARA_CONST_EXPR(s) (1 ? 0 : ((void)(s),0))
#define PARA(s) PARA_STR(s) + PARA_CONST_EXPR(s)
```

for code:

```
#define ID 10

char *str1 = "Test" PARA(ID);
char *str2 = "Test2" PARA(ID2);
```

it would generate error message:

```
prog.c:22:27: error: ‘ID2’ undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean ‘ID’?
   22 | char *str2 = "Test2" PARA(ID2);
```

It would for any defined `ID` like enum or even a struct.

```
enum { ID = 5 };
struct { int _; } ID;
```

The case of initializer for `char[]` is more complex and less reliable.
You can try to hijack the declaration of the variable by adding `,` and inserting a new declaration of some pointer dummy object. This object would be initialized with constant `0` (aka NULL) formed from a constant expression that depends on both `s` (to detect undefined identifier) and on the dummy variable itself to silence warnings about unused variable.
The name of dummy object has to be unique.
It can be formed with a help of `__LINE__` macro or non-standard though popular `__COUNTER__` macros.

After some experimentation I found:

```
#define PARA_STR(s) "<PARA"#s">"
#define PARA_CONST_EXPR(s,var) (1 ? 0 : ((void)(s),(void*)&var))
#define CONCAT_(a,b) a ## b
#define CONCAT(a,b) CONCAT_(a,b)
#define PARA_DECL(s, var) *var = PARA_CONST_EXPR(s,var)
#define PARA_UNIQ_VAR CONCAT(para__, __LINE__)
#define PARA(s) PARA_STR(s), PARA_DECL(s, PARA_UNIQ_VAR)


int ID;

char str1[] = "Test" PARA(ID);
char str2[] = "Test2" PARA(ID2); // detected

char *strp1 = "Test" PARA(ID);
char *strp2 = "Test" PARA(ID2); // detected

int main() {
    char str3[] = "Test3" PARA(main);
    char str4[] = "Test3" PARA(main2); // detected
}
```

It works quite well as long as `PARA` is used at the end of the initializer.

Comment: Thank you for looking into! Unfortunately, `PARA` is normally not used at the end of the initializer. I still try to understand the expression `((void)(s),0))`. Do you know a resource explaining the hijack of declarations?

Comment: @Noetzold, `((void)(s),0)` is the same as `(s, 0)`.Comma operator works by discarding the first value, returning only the second.  Cast to `void` is used to silence the compiler on warning about unused value. This trick allows creating an expression that uses `s` but which value does not depend on `s`

Comment: @Noetzold, I've invented the term of "hijacking of declaration". Basically it means that when a macro `X` is expanded in the declaration i.e. `int a = X;` then `X` can add decalre an extra variable by expanding to `42, b = 1`. So `int a = X;` -> `int a = 42, b = 1;`. It means that the declaration context is hijacked by `X` to let declare extra variables.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation now i got it. Now I understand why it is only working incase PARA is at the end.